# Access 2007 security options to avoid redistribution

Tags: ms-access, security, vba, ms-access-2007

My question is as follows. When I recieve a usage fee for an application I developed in Access 2007 I send out the application to my client, but how do I make sure that the client won't simply copy the database and redistribute it. Thus letting the client's client avoid the usage fee for the application.

I have put a 128-bit encryption on the application to secure the data in the tables  and also converted it from a .Accdb to .Accde to secure the forms, reports, query's and VBA.
Also, I let them sign a legal document in which it states that the application cannot be redistributed unless authorized by me, but of course I'd rather they couldn't even if they tried.

What are my options here? I thought about linking a license code (handmade by me) to a certain MAC-Address that I can retrieve with VBA. And only making the database usable in case they match. But would this even work and is it easy to bypass?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
thanks in advance for any suggestions/replies.

**Edit**: Thanks Dork Programmer for your reply.
In the end I chose to go for the drive volume number to give access to the application. I am aware that this changes when the disk is formatted and there is a slight possibility that it is not unique, however I believe this will have to do as I am unable to retrieve the manufactures hard drive serial number (which would be unique)

In conclusion; the client wil give me their drive vol number, I then add this to a table that holds these numbers. I then apply all my security measures and send the client the app. When the application opens the app will only be usable if a match is found between the clients disk vol number and the values in the table, else it will close the app. Should a client decide to format his/her disk or remove it they could then contact me and I'd add the new number to the approved numbers table and send them the app back.

Answer (score 1):

I just sharing what I did on my ms-access application

1. First, I create some form with the VBA code inside to enter the unique code
2. Then I create some Hidden table to store the unique code and also to store the IP address/Computer name that database located.

Based on my experience, this method is quite enough effective to avoid user copying the database or moving it to another computer.